# Angular Application. Navigate to different components based on the trigger ( imperative or popstate ) for same path in routes

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-ui-router

Angular Application - I have a component P which has a button with router path to access component C (imperative trigger). How can I navigate to some other component if the user manipulates the URL directly in browser ( popstate trigger) instead of navigating through component P.

How to achieve different behavior for same route but different trigger mechanism ?

Comment: what kind of manipulating do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to differentiate between component called from p to c and loading component C directly from url ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean in these few words, can you elaborate on what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I meant when the same url is accessed directly from browser by manuaaly hitting  and through a button inside my application it should behave differently. So how could I differentiate between both types of trigger

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue, I might have given less information. But I found a work around. Posted as a solution

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Yes exactly what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , when we hit a router link we can check the navigationStart property of router and in that we can see if the navigation trigger is **imperative** or **popstate** or **hashChange**.
 In case of **popstate** - it is directly hit from browser.
 In case of **imperative** - the hit is from inside the application itself.
So I can place a guard (canActivate()) on the router link to check which trigger it is and control the behavior of the URL.

Note:- hashChange trigger I am not much aware of how it occurs. (If some one knows do contribute)